# VueJS: How to make a nested router-view always render one of its routes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

TL:DR;**Is it possible to make the `router-view` display a component without being on that component route ?**

I am trying to imitate a carousel effect using `router-view` inside a child component.
The problem is that if I don't click on a `router-link` the `router-view` displays nothing.
I want to make on of the `router-link` be active when no other is in order to force the `router-view` to always display something.

App.vue with the top `router-view`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

Router index.js:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "LandingPage",
    component: LandingPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/icons",
        name: "Icons",
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../components/portfolio/Icons.vue"),
      },
   ],
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        selector: to.hash,
        behavior: "smooth",
        // offset: { x: 0, y: 75 }
      };
    } else {
      return savedPosition;
    }
  },
});
```

LandingPage.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
      <Home></Home>
      <About></About>
      <Portfolio></Portfolio>
      <Contact></Contact>
  </div>
</template>
```

Portfolio.vue with the second `router-view`:

```
<template>
  <section id="portfolio">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="slide in slider" :key="slide.path">
          <router-link :to="`/${slide.link}`">{{ slide.text }}</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <router-view />
  </section>
</template>
```

As you can see I have only one route, which is `/` for the top `router-view`. This will render `LandingPage`.
I use hashes to navigate to the components inside `LandingPage` like so: `<router-link :to="{ path: '/', hash:` #${link.path} `}">`

I am trying to make the `router-link :to="/icons"` active and the `Icons` component render inside `Portfolio`'s `router-view` when no other link **from Portfolio** is active.
It's important for it to remain active only inside Portfolio, because I have a Navbar with other `router-link` which go to various hashes inside `LandingPage`.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: I don't imagine what you are trying to say. I don't get it.

Comment: Vue-Router does not use hashes or query parameters to distinguish between routes - only the path piece of the URL is used. You should replace hashes with route parameters - or if you insist on using the same route then use query parameters and `beforeRouteUpdate` hook in the component.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I'm sorry, but I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you want to show Icon when the route is '/'.
To define a default sub-route you need to have a route with an empty value (path:'').
Now if you don't want to change path use the '[alias](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-alias/app.js)' mechanism.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "LandingPage",
    component: LandingPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/icons",
        alias: '',
        name: "Icons",
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../components/portfolio/Icons.vue"),
      },
   ],
  },
];
```

If alias doesn't meet your needs, define your sub-route twice(One by empty path second by '/icons')
You can also define /icons as the main route:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/icons",
    name: "LandingPage",
    component: LandingPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        name: "Icons",
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../components/portfolio/Icons.vue"),
      },
   ],
  },
];
```